# C# WPF app hangs in debug mode, works perfect in VS 2015 breakpoint mode

Tags: c#, windows, forms, debugging, exception

I have C# Windows Forms Application created in Visual Studio 2015. Application is made to calculate some data, then assign it to predefined int variables and show them in output console.

Problem is that application is going through all code without errors in breakpoint mode, till the end of whole code and give me in console output that I want. But if I run program through Debug Mode(F5) or even without Debug Mode ( Ctrl+F5 ) then I have no output and program hangs. After some amount of time it throwns an ContentDeadlockException.

Thanks for the answers.

Edit:

OK, so here is uncompleted GUI of my application : [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMZqt.jpg)
When I click the "Run Algorithm" button, program hangs in debug mode. If I try to debug in breakpoint mode, run statement after statement it is going right.

There is my code of that form:

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class IterationAlgorithm : Form
    {
        //Random random;
        List<IZadPrac> workersList = new List<IZadPrac>();
        List<IZadPrac> jobsList = new List<IZadPrac>();
        public bool[,] generateTable(bool[,] tableGiven)
        {
            bool isRight = false;
            while (!isRight)
            {
                Array.Clear(tableGiven, 0, tableGiven.Length);

                for (int i = 0; i < tableGiven.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    tableGiven[i, random.Next(tableGiven.GetLength(1))] = true;
                }

                int jobsTimeSum;

                for (int i = 0; i < workersList.Count; i++)
                {
                    jobsTimeSum = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < jobsList.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (tableGiven[j, i]) jobsTimeSum += jobsList[j].showJobTime();
                        if (workersList[i].showWorkerTime() < jobsTimeSum)
                        {
                            j = jobsList.Count;
                            i = workersList.Count;
                            isRight = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isRight = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return tableGiven;
        }
public int FindFunctionMin(bool[,] tableGiven)
        {
            int goalFunction = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < jobsList.Count; i ++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < workersList.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (tableGiven[i, j])
                    {
                        goalFunction += workersList[j].showCompetitions()[i] * jobsList[i].showJobTime();
                        j = workersList.Count;
                    }
                }
            }
            return goalFunction;
        }

        public IterationAlgorithm(List<IZadPrac> ListaPrac, List<IZadPrac> ListaZad)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.workersList = ListaPrac;
            this.jobsList = ListaZad;
            bool[,] boolTable = new bool[jobsList.Count, workersList.Count];
            Array.Clear(boolTable, 0, boolTable.Length);
            //List<bool[,]> listOfTables = new List<bool[,]>();
            //int counter = 0;
            //int goalFunctionTemp = 0;
            List<int> funkcjaCelu = new List<int>();

            List<IZadPrac> workListCopy = new List<IZadPrac>();
            List<IZadPrac> jobListCopy = new List<IZadPrac>();
            int goalFunctionTemp = 999999;

            workListCopy = jobsList;
            jobListCopy = workersList;


        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool[,] booltable = new bool[jobsList.Count, workersList.Count];
            Array.Clear(booltable, 0, booltable.Length);
            int counter = 0;
            int max;
            int functionmin = 999999;
            bool error = false;
            List<int> funkcjaCelu = new List<int>();

            if(textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                max = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                while (counter < max)
                {

                    int number = FindFunctionMin(generateTable(booltable));
                    if (functionmin > number) functionmin = number;
                    counter++;

                }
                label2.Text = "The smallest value of function " + functionmin.ToString();
            }



        }
    }
}`

When I press on pause button in debug mode, then breapoint is at "GenerateTable" function.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Give us some code. Its like shooting in the dark at this point. From what I see you have a race condition in your application with parallel threads

Answer (score 0):

OK I found solution... my Random instance was created too fast in for loop, so I moved it on top of while loop and program works fine now.